# MEX: C2143 error: stdio.h missing ')' before '*'

Tags: windows, matlab, visual-c++, mex, stdio

I am trying to compile a bunch of C files using MEX under windows 7 (64 bits). In order to do that I installed Matlab R2014a and the Microsoft SDK 7.1 with the C/C++ utilities.

The fact is that when I execute the command:

```
 mex -g file_1.c file_2.c
```

I got many error like the one posted in the title.

I already tried setting MEX to use the c and c++ VS compiler because I thought it was an error due to the bad compiler choose, but unfortunately it didn't.

Does anyone have some hints what could I try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try including stdio.h (ie the system's own include files) before the other includes?

Comment: I just did it and now the errors are in the file_1.c and file_2.c. They are all like the title.

Comment: I think you'll need to create a minimal test case, the error(s) without context don't help much in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your first comment help me a lot. Afterwards I only had to change a bit the code ans everything succeed for what your second comment help me again.